# How do I get more Humble Scrap?

Tags: monster-hunter-4-ultimate

I got a second Palico, the poor thing doesn't have armor or weapons. Since I want to make new weapons/armor I need Humble Scrap.

How do I obtain this Humble Scrap?

Comment: You need to play the caravan quests some more before you can get scraps

Comment: usually they come with some sort of equipment. Check the palico equipment box and see what you have.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Keep playing the Caravan quests. Eventually you will save the Meownster Hunters. After completing the quest, you will unlock the Meownster Hunters on the island.

By doing so, you'll unlock a minigame, where you can send up to 5 Palicos on a hunt for up to 3 monsters. Successfully killing these monsters rewards scraps correlating to the monster killed, and occasionally you will get humble scraps as well. There are several monsters that you can kill this way, so the Palico equipment can get fairly varied. They'll all need humble scraps.

One thing to remember is that this minigame is like the fishing game. You get 1 provision every hunt that you do. The minigame has 3 monsters, and you can attempt 1 monster for each provision that you have. It's best to do the game every 3 hunts to maximize on scraps.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that treasure chests in meownster hunter routes usually give lots of humble/handsome scrap, so if you're short on them, aim for routes with treasure chests!

Answer (score 2):

You can send out Palicos out on their own quests (Palicos in reserve, not from your 1st Stringers) by talking to your housekeeping Palico in your house or from the board on Sunsnug Isle.

Humble scraps will sometimes drop from successful quests.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit late, but to add on to this, you ARE given a weapon for the palicos you recieve. You simply have to equip it from the board at the back of your room.

Comment: I completely missed that. Found it by now though.